# How do I make a mesh deform only due to collision and not movement?

Tags: collision, soft-body

I have a complex mesh, and my goal is to have certain parts of the mesh deform while the rest stay rigid, and I need those deformations to happen only on collision with another object.

I'm currently using softbody physics, and through vertex groups and weight painting, I have successfully made it so that only certain parts of the mesh deform. (I included this in case it has a big impact on the solution for the real question).

If I move the object in the scene, the parts I want to deform are jiggling. I would like for movement not to impact the mesh at all, so that it only deforms when something collides with it.

If I increase "Mass" by a whole lot, collision deformations look excellent! However, any time the object itself moves, a high mass makes the jiggle extremely pronounced and erratic. If I make "Mass" very small, it doesn't jiggle at all when the object moves which is great, but collisions look way too ripply and erratic

Comment: why don't you keyframe the mass? for moving low mass, for collision high mass?

Comment: Or maybe disable the *Softbody modifier with keyframes while the object moves...? (not sure if the momentum gets lost then)